# Is the Axiom of Union independent of the rest of ZF?

Tags: set-theory, independence-results, lo.logic

Short version: Is the axiom of union independent of the rest of axioms of ZF?

NO) [Tourlakis (2003)](http://books.google.es/books?id=zwv0RgAACAAJ&dq=tourlakis+set+vol+2&hl=es&ei=vWbOTu6YHYmb8QP8-MzODw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA) says in p. 177 that the axiom of union can be derived from the rest of ZF if an appropriate version of collection axiom[*] is chosen. The quote is:

«Bourbaki (1966b) adopts the axiom of pairing, but adopts collection version (2), and proves both separation and union»

YES) In the other hand, I have read [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48365/minimal-subset-of-axioms-for-zfc/54328#54328) and [here](http://tiddlyspace.com/bags/oxkunengroup_public/tiddlers/4.7%3A%2520Models%2520for%2520ZFC-Replacement%2520and%2520ZFC-Unions) something like "$H_{\kappa}$ is a model for ZF-Union+¬Union", where $\kappa$ was $\beth_\omega$ or a singular cardinal.

Any reference on the subject would be highly appreciated. I apologize in advance if the question is too basic (not a mathematician!). Also, I have googled it and followed some false trails before asking here. Thanks.

[*] The appropriate version of collection is apparently weaker (or equivalent at most) than the collection axiom that he is adopting in his text. I think the statement is:

$(∀x)(∃z)(∀y)({\mathcal P} [x, y] → y ∈ z) → (\forall A)(\exists B)(\forall y)(y\in B\leftrightarrow (\exists x\in A){\mathcal P}[x,y])$

I have translated the notation from III.8.12 and III.2 (obviating any reference to ur-elements).

EDIT: Thank you very much for the answers, they were really helpful.

Comment: Can you write down what the "appropiate version of collection" is?

Comment: If the answers ware helpful, pick one that helped the most and 'accept' it by clicking on the tick. This is better than editing your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The usual version of collection is the second one in Kaveh's answer.  It, with the remaining axioms, won't give the axiom of union.  A counterexample is given in the question, except for a slightly unusual definition of $H_\kappa$ for singular $\kappa$; it should be the collection of those sets $x$ such that each member of the transitive closure $TC(\{x\})$ has cardinality $<\kappa$.  (This does not imply that the whole $TC(\{x\})$ has cardinality $<\kappa$, which is the usual meaning of $H_\kappa$.)

The "appropriate version" of collection used by Bourbaki seems appropriate mainly in the sense that the axiom of union has been built in.

Comment: The claim about the "weakness" of the "appropriate" version of the collection axiom still puzzled me; but I realize now that it is probably irrelevant, since the implication is proved using the rest of axioms of ZF (including union).

Comment: Shoenfield, *Mathematical Logic* also uses the "appropriate" version. Do I understand correctly that you are saying there are reasons to prefer the "usual" version?

Comment: As far as I can see, I think there is no special reason to adopt the "appropriate" version of Bourbarki or Shoenfield (but remember: I am not an specialist, not even a mathematician!). I simply got confused about of the independence of Unions by the statements in Tourlakis (2003).

Comment: @Tct: Well, I'm asking if there is a reason to choose the usual one, which is not the same as asking if there is a reason not to choose the appropriate one. :P

Answer (score 6):

The axiom is

$$\forall x \ \exists y \ \forall z \ (\varphi(z,x) \to z\in y) \to \forall X \ \exists Y \ \forall y \ (y \in Y \leftrightarrow  \exists x\in X \ \varphi(y,x)) $$

Consider

$$\forall x \ \exists y \ \forall z \ (z\in x \to z\in y) \to \forall X \ \exists Y \ \forall y \ (y \in Y \leftrightarrow  \exists x\in X \ y\in x ) $$

This is an instance of the axiom. Now the left side is true (take $y=x$). The right side expresses the existence of the union of $X$.

---

The other version of the axiom:

$$\forall x\in X \ \exists y \ \varphi(x,y) \to \ \exists Y \ \forall x\in X \ \exists y\in Y \ \varphi(x,y)$$

Comment: The second part of your answer doesn't seem to do what you want, since $Y$ could just be the given $X$, not its union (assuming $P$ is intended to mean power set).  



Comment: @Andreas, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Let me add a nice remark I just became aware of: In

> Greg Oman. [*On the axiom of union*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00153-009-0163-1), Arch. Math. Logic, **49 (3)**, (2010), 283–289. [MR2609983 (2011g:03122)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2609983),

Oman clarifies precisely which unions can be proved to exist in $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathrm{Union}$: $\bigcup x$ exists iff $\{|y|\colon y\in x\}$ is bounded. In particular, $A\cup B$ exists for any sets $A,B$.

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/498256/462) MSE question for details. The proof uses in essential ways both choice and replacement.

(Curiously, I do not know of an original reference for the fact that $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathrm{Union}$ does not suffice to prove the existence of *infinite* unions, the usual argument being the one in the body of the question, and in Andreas's answer. It would be nice to have the reference, so it can be added [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/434100/462).)

Comment: When you say bounded, do you mean...?

Comment: There is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $|y|\le\alpha$ for all $y\in x$.

Comment: But... isn't that true for *any* set in $\sf ZFC$?

Comment: Yes. We are working in $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathrm{Union}$.

Comment: So does that mean that "every set can be well-ordered" is not provable from $\sf ZFC-Union$? (It makes sense, but still...)

Comment: It is provable.

Comment: So the axiom of union is in fact provable from the rest of the axioms? I must be missing something. I knew I should have had another beer...

Comment: Asaf, think of the example in Andreas's answer.

Comment: I'm sure that if I would have had that extra Guinness I would have picked up on the fact that there might be a cofinal set of ordinals... :-)