# Is there any research on set theory without extensionality axiom?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

In practice (say, in computer science), collections with many "labels" ("identities"), or collections which occur in many copies, are more frequently used than sets. Such collections do not satisfy the extensionality axiom, i.e. two different such collections A and B can have same elements (I would then say that A and B are "extensionally equivalent"). I am aware that extensionality axiom is independent of other axioms in ZF and possibly in other axiomatic set theories.

Is there any (systematic) research of a set theory without extensionality axiom? Say, how a model of such a theory can be obtained in ZF, or whether the model of such a theory ratio the "extensionality equivalence" is a model of a set theory with extensionality axiom? It sounds probable that such collections have to do with multisets, i.e. sets, the elements of which can occur in many copies - the atoms must be allowed to occur in many copies, once such collections can have many copies). By the way, is there an axiomatized multiset theory?

Comment: [ETCS](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS)?

Comment: @DavidRoberts: This sounds to be ETCS, but the language of category theory is difficult for me. Is there a "classical" exposition of ETCS?

Comment: @IoachimD You might take a look at Mike Shulman's SEAR in the nLab.

Answer (score 24):

Going the other direction, it turns out that classical ZF (using collection + separation) can be embedded in the theory where you drop extensionality---everything in classical set theory is still possible in a sense even when extensionality is not available. The idea is that when one lacks extensionality, one may recover it by defining an equivalence of sets, namely, that of having the same members, but then one wants really to define sets as equivalent when they have equivalent members, and so in in a transfinite refining process of the equivalence relation. The result is that in any model of ZF- without extensionality, one can define a corresponding model of ZF.

This is proved in *Harvey Friedman*, [**The consistency of classical set theory relative to a set theory with intuitionistic logic**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=347565), *J. Symbolic Logic* **38** (1973), 315--319.  The main point of the article is not this extensionality issue, but rather to embed classical ZF in an intuitionist logical system.

So although the axiom of extensionality seems fundamental to set theory—and one can find many instances in the literature describing extensionality as the most fundamental axiom—in fact one does not need it to develop set theory.

The theory used in that article is a theory of the kind you seek, a set theory lacking extensionality.

Meanwhile, as Asaf Karagila points out in the comments below, one cannot expect to recover classical ZF in the version of ZF without extensionality, if this is axiomatized with replacment rather than collection. This is because Dana Scott proved that this version of ZF-E is interpretable in Z, and so the consistency strength is strictly less than full ZF, if consistent.

- Dana Scott, [More on the axiom of extensionality](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=163838), 1961 Essays on the foundations of mathematics pp. 115–131 Magnes Press, Hebrew Univ., Jerusalem.

My perspective on this result is that it shows that we should not axiomatize ZF-E using only replacement, since Scott's model violates the collection axiom in the same way that the Zermelo universe $V_{\omega+\omega}$ violates collection. A similar issue arises in other weakenings of ZFC, such as in the case of [ZFC-powerset](http://jdh.hamkins.org/what-is-the-theory-zfc-without-power-set/) and [ZFC-foundation](http://jdh.hamkins.org/foundation-axiom-and-self-embeddings-of-the-universe/), where one should typically use collection+separation rather than replacement.

Comment: The article is on JSTOR: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2272068?uid=3739832&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21104076369697.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the consistency of $\sf ZFC-Ext$ is strictly weaker than that of $\sf ZFC$. So your answer seems a bit strange.

Comment: @AsafKaragila can you post a reference for that? It would seem to contradict this old result of Friedman's.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=163838 <-- See the last paragraph of the review.

Comment: @Asaf: ZFC - Ext with replacement is quite weak. ZFC - Ext with collection is equiconsistent with ZFC.

Comment: @Emil: Yes, that is also pointed out in the review. But $\sf ZF$ is not usually formed with collection, but with replacement. You can't just say something like "ZF without extensionality" and mean "with collections", that's not the usual interpretation.

Comment: The explanation would seem to be that they have slightly different versions of ZF, with Scott using replacement rather than collection, and this seems to be key to the argument. That is, he gets replacement just because there are too many automorphisms. (And this is a very similar issue to that arising in my work on ZFC-power set http://jdh.hamkins.org/what-is-the-theory-zfc-without-power-set/) The reviewer Robin Gandy briefly criticizes this in that paragraph, and I would think that the argument itself shows that Scott's version isn't what we should mean by ZF minus extensionality.

Comment: Oh, I see after posting my comment that Emil has also made the same point....

Comment: Joel, whether or not that is true, the canonical formulation of $\sf ZFC$ is not with the collection schema, but with the replacement schema. Expecting people to immediately guess that in one situation or another we should replace one schema by another is unrealistic. In particular when the OP is not an expert in set theory, and may or may not know about the collection schema and when to use it instead of replacement.

Comment: I disagree with that. For example, my paper on ZFC-powerset shows quite clearly that if you say "ZFC minus powerset" you definitely should NOT mean the version with replacement. I agree that people should not have to guess, but that isn't what is going on here, since both Scott and Friedman make clear what their theory is. And as it turns out, Friedman has the more robust theory. Scott's theory is flawed in the same way that ZFC-P with replacement is flawed, and Scott himself essentially shows this.

Comment: Yes, but you don't make it clear in your answer. That's my point, and just to prove my point, see my first comment being baffled on this fact, that it didn't cross my mind to take $\sf ZF$ with collections rather than replacement, and I think I know at least a bit, even if not much more than a bit, about set theory.

Comment: I am sorry if there was a misunderstanding. Personally, I axiomatize ZF with collection+separation, and we seem to have more and more evidence that this is the right way to do it, because of the problems arising with various weakenings of the theory if one has only replacement. For example, the same issue arises when dropping foundation, and looking at the anti-foundational theories. See http://jdh.hamkins.org/foundation-axiom-and-self-embeddings-of-the-universe/.

Comment: I have edited to clarify the issue about replacement, which I am glad to learn about. Thanks, Asaf!

Comment: By the way, Joel, I'm not so sure that philosophically speaking, we should be in a rush to change $\sf ZFC$ to something that will end up equiconsistent when removing power set/foundation/extensionality. The fact that from $\sf ZFC$ we can always move to strictly weaker theories by removing axioms, and ensure the existence of models over which we can work what we need to work, seems like a very positive quality of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: Oh, I completely agree with that. To my way of thinking, the fact that we can recover a companion ZFC model hiding beneath any model of ZFC-E  simply affirms that we needn't have bothered omitting it in the first place.

Comment: Joel, I think you may have misunderstood my previous comment. I meant to say that the fact that removing axioms weakens the consistency strength is actually a good thing.

Comment: My perspective is that the fact that replacement ZF minus E is surprisingly weak, while collection ZF minus E is not, shows the value and perhaps more fundamental nature of collection over replacement. (And why are you fixed on the idea that ZFC must use replacement instead of collection? Certainly both axiomatizations are quite commonly found.)

Comment: Do you know to what extent this fact is true in weaker theories than ZF?  In particular, what about intuitionistic set theory with function-sets, but without powersets, collection, or unbounded separation (corresponding to the internal language of a $\Pi$-pretopos)?

Comment: @MikeShulman No, I don't quite know the full extent of this phenomenon, and it is something that I have been wanting to understand much more fully.

Answer (score 6):

There is a bunch of works on set theories featuring the naive (Cantor-style) comprehension axiom, over  logics weaker than classical (such as, fragments of linear logic and their extensions), which abstain from extensionality because its presence introduces the contraction principle and, in tow, a contradiction. [1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1567832608000179) gives the gist and a sample of references.

Two more comments: I don't think "practice" is a good enough impulse for omitting extensionality from ZF, because practice usually won't make use of all the strata ZF has to offer. Second, if "without extensionality" means just the omission of the axiom Ext, then the model of such a theory is easy to imagine since any model of ZF is also a model of ZF without Ext.