# Shortest axiom of infinity for foundationless set theory

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations, axioms

Let $T$ be the theory with a binary symbol $\in$, an unary symbol $S$, and the following axioms:

[Axiom of extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality):
\begin{equation}
    \forall x \forall y (\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \rightarrow x = y)
\end{equation}

[Axiom of heredity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory#The_axioms):
\begin{equation}
    \forall x (S x \leftrightarrow \forall y (y \in x \rightarrow S y))
\end{equation}

[Axiom schema of comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Unrestricted_comprehension):
\begin{equation}
    \forall x (\phi x \rightarrow S x) \rightarrow \exists y \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \phi x)
\end{equation}
for every formula $\phi$ not containing $S$.

This entails the existence of the [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_empty_set) (as well as any [hereditarily finite set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set)) and, over sets that satisfy $S$, [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_power_set), [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union), [pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing), and [specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification).

---

Let $I$ be the formula
\begin{equation}
    \exists x (S x \land \varnothing \in x \land \forall y (y \in x \rightarrow y \cup \{y\} \in x))
\end{equation}

asserting the existence of an [inductive set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity#Formal_statement), where $\varnothing \in x$ and $y \cup \{y\} \in x$ are expanded according to their usual definitions in set theory. What is the [shortest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207352/simplest-axiom-that-entails-the-existence-of-an-infinite-set) formula $\psi$ such that $T, \psi \vdash I$ and $T, \psi \nvdash \bot$? How strong is the resulting theory $T, \psi$? Since $T$ lacks [foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), such a $\psi$ must deal with the possibility of non-well-founded sets.

Some possible candidates, starting with $I$ itself:

\begin{align}
\psi_1 &= \exists x (S x \land \varnothing \in x \land \forall y (y \in x \rightarrow y \cup \{y\} \in x))
\\
&= \tiny{\exists x (S x \land \exists y (y \in x \land \neg \exists z (z \in y)) \land \forall y (y \in x \rightarrow \exists z (z \in x \land \forall w (w = y \lor w \in y \leftrightarrow w \in z))))}
\\
\psi_2 &= \forall x (S x \rightarrow \exists y (S y \land x \in y \land \forall z (z \in y \rightarrow \{z\} \in y)))
\\
&= \tiny{\forall x (S x \rightarrow \exists y (S y \land x \in y \land \forall z (z \in y \rightarrow \exists w (\forall t (t \in w \leftrightarrow t = z) \land w \in y))))}
\end{align}

Comment: the formula $\phi x $ must not contain $y$ free also.

Comment: I think the following is shorter: $\exists x (S x \land \exists k (k \in x) \land \\\forall y \forall z (y \in x \land \forall m (m \in z \to m = y) \to z \in x))$

Comment: In your second predicate, the first $w$ is not quantified upon? I think you mean $x$ but you accidentally wrote $w$.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar You’re right. Fixed.

Comment: @I think you need to remove $\forall x(S x$ and just put $\exists x$ before (or after) $\exists y$

Comment: What is the lonely character $u$ doing there at the very end of the post?

Comment: @WlodAA What do you mean? I don't see one.

Comment: It's fine. It was a random artifact. My "window" was too narrow -- it cut off $\ldots w\wedge\ldots$ and left "u" (as the last character of your note) since the right leg of "w" vanished leaving "u" instead.

Comment: Your $\Psi_2$ states that for every set $x$ there exist a set $\ y\ $ such that $\ \{x\ z\ \{z\}\}\subseteq y $ (right? -- $x=z$ and $x\ne z$ are both possible).

Comment: @WlodAA I intended for it to say that $z \in y \rightarrow \{z\} \in y$ but I might have to recheck the formula.

Comment: One could introduce macro-substatements. It'd help (us and you) to understand your statements.

Comment: @WlodAA I might add some abbreviated versions. The reason I used the expanded versions is to show exactly how long each candidate is in the internal language.

Comment: For each macro, its length can be stated as a comment. This would help to see the length explicitly as the sum of the macros' lengths. BTW, what's wrong with the axiom about a family of sets which has no maximal element w.r. to $\subseteq\,$?

Comment: @WlodAA Can you write the formula for your axiom? I could add it to the candidates.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I think [removing extensionality](https://mathoverflow.net/a/168307/74578), adding a form of collection, and adding infinity might be sufficient for this theory to interpret ZFC. Since powerset, union, specification, collection, and infinity are sufficient to interpret ZFC (I believe).

Comment: Actually, I wonder if replacement is derivable. [Ackermann set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#AckeSetTheo), for example, derives replacement without an explicit axiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REMARK**  I hope that *negation* is legal. Perhaps some $Sx$ statements can be harmlessly removed. Feel free to polish the statement below (I am not a logician).

**STATEMENT**

Set $b$ stands for *big* (infinite). Also, set $y$ strictly contains set $x$.

\begin{align}
\psi
&= \exists b (S b \land \exists a (a\in b) \land \forall x (x \in b \rightarrow \exists y (x \subsetneq y \in b)))
\\
&= \tiny{\exists b\,(Sb\land \exists a (a\in b) \land \forall x\,(x\in b\to
    \exists y\,(y\in b\land\forall z\,(z\in x\to z\in y)\land \neg (x = y))))}
\end{align}

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, thank you. (I was fighting non-existing logical dragons).

Comment: If $\ \emptyset\ $ is legal then I can save 2 characters.

Comment: You mean in the external language?

Comment: Can't $\exists a$ be moved inside to capture just $a \in b$?

Comment: @user76284, first of all, thank you for your edit. I could remove $\ \exists_a\ $ and replace $\ a\in b\ $ by $\ \emptyset\in b.\ $ In general, in the context of the OP Question (nothing wrong about it!) I felt uncomfortable and extra defensive about my formula. I am not a logician hence I don't know the customs, habits, ... to be obeyed in a thread as this.

Comment: Wouldn't the resulting formula be longer in the internal language, since you have to say $\exists a (a \in b \land \neg \exists c (c \in a))$ rather than just $\exists a (a \in b)$?

Comment: @user76284, oh, yes! That's why I was/am uneasy about this game, I don't know the formal rules. (On the other hand, this kind of optimizing formulas are attractive to me anyway).

Comment: I moved $\exists a$ inside the conjunct. This doesn't change the length of the formula but it does make it a bit clearer, I think.

Comment: @user76284, u'r right, now the distance between the symbols to be associated is shorter (local formula understanding is easier than global). I don't see the edit yet, I hope that it will show up soon when admins have time to look at it.

Comment: This is slightly longer than the one in my question but I'll accept it :)

Comment: @user76284, you're too kind, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something like Separation by $\neg S$: $$\forall a \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in a \land \neg Sy)$$
The idea is that if we define *natural* as: *well founded transitive set of transitive sets, that when nonempty then it must have a predecessor, and such that every nonempty element of it must have a predecessor*, then this separation would prevent having a natural that fulfills $\neg S$. Otherwise any such a natural $n$ would have a nonempty subset of it that is the set of all of its elements that fulfill $\neg S$, but that set wont have a minimal! Thus $n$ won't be well founded, which contradicts $n$ being a natural. So this theory would prove that any natural fulfills $S$, therefore by set construction proving the existence of a set of all naturals, which is an inductive set!.

However, I do suspect some kind of inconsistency lurking here or there?!

Regarding the consistency issue, I'd say that if the axiom of Heredity is weakened to two axioms:

Axiom of Heredity: $$\forall x (Sx \to \forall y \in x (Sy))$$

Axiom of Subsets: $$\forall x \forall y (Sx  \land y \subset x \to Sy)$$

And if we weaken the Axiom of comprehension as to additionally require all parameters of $\phi$ to satisfy $S$, and stipulate the asserted set to satisfy $S$.

Then the resulting theory plus Separation by $\neg S$ is a proper fragment of [Muller](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF)'s class theory! And so it's consistent relative to Muller's class theory.

So the question of consistency of addition of Separation by $\neg S$ to the axioms stated by the $OP$ is mostly related to the upward heredity statement $$ \forall x (\forall y \in x (Sy) \to S(x))$$, and to unleashing parameters in comprehension. Those need to be checked.

**[Addendum]:** The addition of separation by $\neg S$ to the axioms of the theory presented here is ***INCONSISTENT***:

Proof: define von Neumann ordinal as a transitive set of transitive sets, that has every nonempty subset of it having a minimal element with respect to relation $\in$, that is:

$$\text{ von Neumann ordinal}(x) \iff \\ transitive(x) \land \forall y \in x (transitive(y)) \land \\\forall z \subseteq x (z \neq \emptyset \to \exists m \in z \forall n \in z (n \not \in m))$$

Now clearly from Separation by $\neg S$ we'll easily prove (from Heredity) that every von Neumann ordinal satisfy $S$! Thus having a set of all of them (comprehension), enacting Burali-Forti.

However the result doesn't affect the suggested weaker fragment of Muller's set theory that I've exposited here. But the answer to the shortest axiom that would imply infinity when added to the axioms of the theory presented here is still an open question.

Comment: Does the weakened axiom of heredity allow us to prove $S \varnothing$?

Comment: Yes, simply let $\phi$ be any false formula, and the result is the empty set satisfying $S$.Notice that comprehension needs to stipulate that the asserted set satisfy $S$

Comment: You mean comprehension needs the extra conjunct $\exists y \dots \land S y$?

Comment: @user76284, Exactly!