# What's the exact consistency strength of this proper fragment of Muller's class theory?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

This question is largely connected to the question presented [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354994/shortest-axiom-of-infinity-for-foundationless-set-theory).

Let $T$ be the theory extending first order logic with equality, with primitives of a binary symbol $\in$, an unary symbol $S$; and the following axioms:

Axiom of extension: \begin{equation}
    \forall x \forall y (\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \rightarrow x = y)
\end{equation}

Axiom of heredity:\begin{equation}
    \forall x \forall y (S x \land (y \in x \lor y \subset x) \to S y)
\end{equation}

Axiom schema of reflection:\begin{equation}
   S p_1,...,S p_n \to \\ \forall y (\phi y \rightarrow S y) \rightarrow \exists x: S x \land \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi y)
\end{equation}
for every formula $\phi$ not containing $S$ nor $``x"$, whose parameters are among $p_1,..,p_n$ symbols.

Axiom of $\neg S$-separation: 
\begin{equation}
    \forall a \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in a \land \neg Sy)
\end{equation}

This theory is a proper fragment of [Muller](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF)'s class theory. It can prove axioms of: empty set, pairing, set union, power, separation, and infinity over objects fulfilling $S$. It is stronger than Zermelo since it can prove the existence of $\aleph_{\omega}$ that fulfills $S$, and much higher cardinals!

> Question: What's the exact consistency strength of this theory? And in particular can it interpret $ZFC$ the way [Ackermann](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484370900112) set theory does?

Comment: Does $\subset$ here represent $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$?

Comment: @user76284, the second.but it doesn't really matter, you can used it for the first for shortness purposes.