# Extensionality, regularity, NBG--

Tags: set-theory

Suppose you in a more comprehensive framework has the result that U is the least set such that all axioms of NBG-- (NBG, minus extensionality and regularity), hold; replacement is here, as expected, obtained relative to the least class containing U and (membership class) E, and as well closed under complement, intersection, domain, Cartesian product with U, circular permutation and transposition.

It seems obvious that regularity holds for U.

Is it obvious that extensionality holds for U?

Edit:

The question(s) presuppose that NBG is consistent.

Edit 2: I changed the original V to U, so as to avoid confusion with the cumulative hierarchy.

Comment: What is closure under E?

Comment: @JamesHanson E={(x,y)|(x,y)\in V\wedge x\in y}

Comment: How can we construct $V$ without Extensionality? Also, do you allow "re-interpreting" the equality symbol over $V$ to a different equivalence relation?

Comment: @HanulJeon "How can we construct  without Extensionality?" Notice that the V is not the V as in the cumulative hierarchy. I edit and substitute with U. The details are rather too complex to divulge her. But notice that the axioms apart from extensionality are all, roughly, of the form \forall x(x\in U\to \Gamma(x)\in U); extensionality and regularity cannot be brought to that form.

Comment: @HanulJeon "Also, do you allow "re-interpreting" the equality symbol over   to a different equivalence relation?" Equality is taken à la Leibniz, with the improvement by Whitehead & Russell in PM, as \forall u(a\in u\to b\in u).

Comment: It's not really clear to me that regularity is going to hold in $U$. In my experience when you try to throw away *both* extensionality and foundation you start to really lose the ability to form inductive constructions (like the class of hereditarily well-founded sets). Do you have a proof of this statement?

Comment: @JamesHanson I have a proof, by means of induction, that all members of U are wellfounded.

Comment: @JamesHanson Incidentally, Scott showed that ZF minus extensionality and foundation interprets ZF minus foundation: @InBook{Scott1961,
 author = {Scott, D.},
 ALTeditor = {editor},
 title = {More on the Axiom of Extensionality},
 OPTchapter = {chapter},
 OPTpublisher = {publisher},
 year = {1961},
 OPTkey = {key},
 OPTvolume = {volume},
 OPTnumber = {number},
 OPTseries = {series},
 OPTtype = {type},
 OPTaddress = {address},
 OPTedition = {edition},
 OPTmonth = {month},
 OPTpages = {207-214},
 note = {In: Bar-Hillel, pp. 115-131},
 OPTannote = {annote},
}

Comment: @JamesHanson @Book{Bar-Hillel1961,
 ALTauthor = {author},
 editor = {Bar-Hillel, Y. and  others}, 
 title = {Essays on the Foundations of Mathematics},
 booksubtitle = {Dedicated to A. A. Fraenkel on his seventieth anniversary},
 publisher = {North-Holland Publishing Company},
 location = {Amsterdam},
 year = {1961},
 OPTkey = {key},
 OPTvolume = {volume},
 OPTnumber = {number},
 OPTseries = {series},
 address = {Amsterdam},
 OPTedition = {First},
 OPTmonth = {month},
 OPTnote = {note},
 OPTannote = {annote},
}

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Are you sure that that's what's shown in *More on the Axiom of Extensionality*? I'm looking at a copy of it right now and it looks like Scott is proving that ZF minus extensionality and foundation is strictly weaker than ZF minus foundations.

Comment: @JamesHanson Yes, I am sure. The result is concisely formulated in the penultimate paragraph of page 130. But the preceding paragraphs are needed to unriddle it.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Okay well then the statement depends in a strong way on the precise formulation of replacement, so I feel like you should specify that when making this kind of statement, especially when the commonly cited result in this area (given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/168307/83901) for instance) is more or less the opposite.

Comment: @JamesHanson The statement I made, which you are characterizing, was incidental, and it is correct. Scott's results are not relevant to any presuppositions I make as regards U.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal I don't think you can really claim that your statement is correct in an unqualified sense when the paper you're citing uses a materially different definition of 'ZF minus extensionality and foundation' and literally states in the second paragraph that ZF minus extensionality and foundation is strictly weaker than ZF minus foundation.

Comment: @JamesHanson I can claim what I claim. Scott has, as you will have noticed, several results in the paper, and it is true that some of his versions of ZF are weakened by deleting extensionality. But there is also the crucial result that one of his versions of ZF is interpretable by the same version of ZF minus extensionality. I also noticed that some accounts of Scott only took the former results into account. But I take Scott's article to be the canonical account, and his account is not given in the second paragraph.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal I'm sorry but I just feel like you are not doing a great job of communicating clearly if you say 'Scott proved X' and point to a paper which leads with saying that it's going to prove not X.

Comment: @JamesHanson I think that you should as well have paid attention to Scott's paragraph three, where he compares his article with 
Gandy, R. On the Axiom of Extensionality II, Journal of  Symbolic  Logic, 24.4, 287-300, 1959. Gandy 1959 showed that NBG minus extensionality interprets NBG. Scott in that paragraph clearly points to $4, and states that a change in replacement leads to the result that the induced version of ZF is interpretable by the same ZF minus extensionality.

Comment: @JamesHanson Moreover, one should read the last sentence of Scott's article: "Hence our conclusion is that ZF($\dot{=}$) is weakened by dropping extensionality, but ZF$(\overset{=}{.}$) is not."

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal I'm not going to deny that I could have spent more time looking at the paper and trying to figure out how it supported your statement, but that doesn't change the fact that's it's pretty basic academic courtesy in situations like this (two seemingly similar definitions with notably distinct consequences) to spell out what you mean as clearly as possible, rather than just spending two seconds pasting some raw BibTeX code and expecting the other person to spend ten minutes poring over a paper.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal Frankly, your original question is also just poorly written. You don't specify *which* version of replacement you are using (which as we have just established, can significantly change the character of the theory in question), and you expected the reader to just know what 'closure under E' and 'circular permutation' mean. In general, you seem to be expecting others to do the lion's share of the work of interpreting your question, rather than putting the effort in yourself to communicate an unambiguous question.

Comment: @JamesHanson I suggest, rather, that you here have revealed a rather too smirk attitude, that is not conducing to find the truth . So I flagged you last two comments.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal regardless of the other parts of the discussion between yourself and James, I share the opinion that pasting two raw BibTeX entries is not helping the reader. Most preferable is something that looks like a proper bibliographic entry as you'd see in a paper, and, if possible, a link (and best of all a stable link). This book does not seem easy to find, so obfuscating its information inside BibTeX code makes matters even harder for people trying to answer and help here.

Comment: I also think that the book is *not* published by North-Holland, but is rather: 

_Essays on the foundations of mathematics, dedicated to A. A. Fraenkel on his seventieth anniversary._ Y. Bar-Hillel, E. I. J. Poznanski, M. O. Rabin and A. Robinson, eds. Jerusalem, the Hebrew University: Magnes Press, 1961 https://www.magnespress.co.il/en/book/Essays_on_the_Foundation_of_Mathematics-535 (cf https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Essays_on_the_Foundations_of_Mathematics/F7xRAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover&bsq=Scott for the paper in question) (**EDIT** this is a second edition!)

Comment: @DavidRoberts It was new to me that Magnes Press published a second edition in 1967. I have been using the first edition of the book, and that was published by North-Holland in 1962; here is a link to a photo of its title page https://public.pdf-archive.com/js37HjFR/.

Comment: Aha, I see. I could not for the life of me find, at that time, a page confirming the existence of the NH edition. I was indeed misled by the "date" entry on 1961 on the Magnus Press page, and the scraped date in Google Books. I found a review of the first edition https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-edinburgh-mathematical-society/article/essays-on-the-foundations-of-mathematics-edited-by-y-bar-hillel-e-i-j-poznanski-m-o-rabin-and-a-robinson-north-holland-publishing-co-1962-351-pp/85897BD7432CC408752E8FA541B74E75

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks for the review! Scott's result is indeed very rarely appreciated in the literature; even in the following otherwise good answer to a query, on the relative consistency of extensionality, the answer is not satisfactory as it does not relate Scott's result on the consistency of extensionality relative to his replacement based (\mathbbmss{ZF}(\dot{=}))-Extensionality. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246921/on-the-relative-consistency-of-the-axiom-of-extensionality

Comment: @DavidRoberts I share the opinion that one, while communicating with others, may, and, in cases, even should, adjust the popularizing efforts so as to be appropriate for the audience addressed. There are various matters which may have weight, in such considerations, as e.g. expediency. Some times one may miss the target, which is unfortunate. At any rate, communicating is not very easy, and it requires efforts from all participants who want to understand.

Answer (score 0):

$U$ can be shown to only contain wellfounded sets by an inductive argument, given the assumption stated that replacement is obtained relative to the least class containing $U$ and $E$, and as well closed complement, intersection, domain, Cartesian product with $U$, circular permutation and transposition. There is no special assumption upon replacement here.

Given Gandy's result in Gandy, R. [On the Axiom of Extensionality II](https://doi.org/10.2307/2963897), Journal of Symbolic Logic, 24.4, 287–300, 1959, one cannot prove the existence of non-extensional classes in $U$.

So the more comprehensive theory may safely postulate that $$(1) \ \ \forall x\in U\colon \mathrm{Wellfounded}(x),$$ and $$(2) \ \ \forall (y,z)\in U^2\colon .\forall x\in U\colon(x\in y\leftrightarrow x\in z)\to \forall x\in U\colon(y\in x\to z\in x).$$