# Is the collection scheme provable in ZF-Regularity?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

By the axiom schema of [collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement#Collection) in ZF, I mean: $$\forall A \exists B \forall x \in A (\exists y \phi(x,y) \to \exists y \in B \phi(x,y))$$, for every formula $\phi$ that doesn't use the symbol $B$.

On the other hand the *axiom schema of replacement* states that if $\phi$ is a first-order formula, and $A$ is a set such that for any $x\in A$ there exists a unique $y$ such that $\phi(x,y)$, then there exists a set $B$ such that $y\in B$ if and only if $\phi(x,y)$ for some $x\in A$.  That is, $B$ is the "image" of $A$ under the "definable class function" $\phi$. [Quoted from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12584/when-does-collection-imply-replacement)]

The proof that I know of uses Regularity. We replace each element $x$ of $A$ by the minimal stage of the cumulative hierarchy that has an element $y$ that satisfy $\phi(x,y)$, then we take the union of the resulting set.

I'm personally not aware of another proof of collection in ZF. Since the above proof clearly depends on Regularity, hence my question:

> Is collection scheme provable in ZF-Regularity?

In other words, is there a model of ZF-Regularity in which collection fails?

Comment: I don’t know who invented the following model: consider a model of $\mathrm{ZFC}^-$ of the form $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}}V_\alpha(A)$ where $A$ is a countable infinite set of Quine atoms, and let $M$ be its submodel consisting of sets whose transitive closure includes only finitely many atoms from $A$. Then $M$ is a model of $\mathrm{ZFC}^-$ where collection fails (specifically, the model satisfies $\forall n\in\omega\,\exists x\,|\mathrm{tc}(x)\cap A|\ge n$, but not $\exists X\,\forall n\in\omega\,\exists x\in X\dots$).

Comment: Your question is already answered in Mathematics Stackexchange. [See the following question and answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1619182/53976)